# What file type can I use to send a contact to a phone over email?

Tags: android, ios, contacts

I have a big list of names and phone numbers I want to send as a file that a smartphone can open and import the list as contacts. Is there a "contacts" filetype of some kind that phones can read?

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to construct a file that looks like a contacts backup file. On your phone make a backup on your contacts then open that file in a basic text editor.
You can then make a file that looks the same as the backup contacts file which you just made and Import that file into your contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard), which you can generate or parse with [CNContactVCardSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactvcardserialization)